# Django unit test to see if model is registered to admin page

Tags: django, unit-testing, admin

I have a URL (`/admin/`) that goes to my Django admin panel (my URL router:`url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),`)

This admin panel includes an admin for the Post model.

That Post model is being registered by a ModelAdmin class called `PostAdmin`.

`admin.py:`

```
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'id',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'author'
    )

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Now I want to write a unit test for this `admin.py file` and I want to check that if you go to the `/admin/` URL you see the Post Model.

How would you do this? I think it would be something like:

```
response = method_gets_url_content(`/admin/`)
assert.response.contains('Post') == True
```

But I'm not sure how to write a test like this since there is no method to get that URL (`/admin`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can work with Django's [*test client* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class MyTests(TestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='foo',
            password='bar'
        )

    def test1(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertContains(response, 'Tags')
```

Comment: thanks. How would you check if a model wasn't there?.. I'm trying this but it's not working: self.assertNotContains(response, 'AnotherModel')

Comment: @NewToJS: normally the `/admin/` page will list all models for which you have registered a `ModelAdmin`.